OpenJDK 21 cannot export Javadoc
I'm using Eclipse 2024-06R and try to export my Javadoc but have no clue on the output error:
  [javadoc] Constructing Javadoc information...
  [javadoc] error: An internal exception has occurred. 
  [javadoc]     (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute)
  [javadoc] Please file a bug against the javadoc tool via the Java bug reporting page
  [javadoc] (https://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (https://bugs.java.com)
  [javadoc] for duplicates. Include error messages and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
  [javadoc] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
  [javadoc]     at java.base/java.net.URL.fromURI(URL.java:721)
  [javadoc]     at java.base/java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1139)
  [javadoc]     at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.doclets.toolkit.util.Extern.readElementListFromURL(Extern.java:443)
  [javadoc]     at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.doclets.toolkit.util.Extern.link(Extern.java:391)
  [javadoc]     at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.doclets.toolkit.util.Extern.link(Extern.java:214)
  [javadoc]     at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.doclets.toolkit.BaseConfiguration.finishOptionSettings0(BaseConfiguration.java:368)
  [javadoc]     at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.doclets.formats.html.HtmlConfiguration.finishOptionSettings0(HtmlConfiguration.java:421)
  [javadoc]     at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.doclets.toolkit.BaseConfiguration.setOptions(BaseConfiguration.java:407)
  [javadoc]     at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.doclets.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:205)
  [javadoc]     at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.doclets.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.run(AbstractDoclet.java:115)
  [javadoc]     at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.doclet.StandardDoclet.run(StandardDoclet.java:103)
  [javadoc]     at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:556)
  [javadoc]     at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Start.begin(Start.java:393)
  [javadoc]     at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Start.begin(Start.java:342)
  [javadoc]     at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Main.execute(Main.java:63)
  [javadoc]     at jdk.javadoc/jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.Main.main(Main.java:52)
  [javadoc] 1 error

I tried JDK 17 & 21, both have the same issue.
I used this method to generate Javaodc for my projects for quite some time. This is something new.

Please always provide a minimal reproducible example. Is this reproducible with a non-modular “Hello world” project? And if so, with which options exactly?
